# Magento top level Category list

Tags: list, magento, categories

I need to create a carousel of categories in a Magento 1.9 site. How can I get a list of top level categories via PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the top level categories of the current store, find all direct children of the store root category:

```
$rootCategoryId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
$rootCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($rootCategoryId);
$topLevelCategories = $rootCategory->getChildrenCategories();
```

`$topLevelCategories` is now a collection of the active top level categories.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've actually used a combination of yours and @K.C. replies and I can now get an array of categories, many thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

This should get you top level category list

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
  ->addAttributeToSelect('*')//or you can just add some attributes
  ->addAttributeToFilter('level', 2)//2 is actually the first level, default is 1
  ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)//if you want only active categories
;
```

And now go `foreach` with `$categories` and print in a way to make it carousel.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've actually used a combination of yours and @fschmengler replies and I can now get an array of categories, many thanks! :)